# Display integers only in AxisY label?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a bar graph depicting number of people. When there's only a few people the Y-axis shows values: 0.5, 1, 1.5 etc ...
It looks kinda silly.

- I can override the interval to 1 (`AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 1`),
  but if there's 100 people it doesn't work
- I can set the
  `AxisY.Maximum = 10`, but that doesn't work with 100 people
- I can set
  `AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = {#}`, but that shows [1,1,2,2] as it
  rounds each label

I realise I could utilise either of the first two options dynamically according to content, but wondered if there's an automatic way to make the labels "integers only"?

Comment: I'm also having this problem, good question.

Comment: What is needed is a MinimumInterval property but there seems to be no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale break to show both small and large numbers on the same axis:

```
// Enable scale breaks
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = true;
// Set the scale break type
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.BreakLineStyle = BreakLineStyle.Wave;
// Set the spacing gap between the lines of the scale break (as a percentage of y-axis)
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing = 2;
// Set the line width of the scale break
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineWidth = 2;
// Set the color of the scale break
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineColor = Color.Red;
// Show scale break if more than 25% of the chart is empty space
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.CollapsibleSpaceThreshold = 25;
// If all data points are significantly far from zero, 
// the Chart will calculate the scale minimum value
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.IsStartedFromZero = AutoBool.Auto;
```

This code sample is pulled straight out of [the mschart samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart), which are a *must* download if you work with the charting controls.

Comment: This is not what is needed. Problem is there is no MinimumInterval property. Ideally What is required is ability to set minimum interval to 1 so that automatic label/tick/grid generation will never generate fractional values.

Answer (score 0):

Following Customize event does the trick. I am basically using a regular expression to detect labels that are not whole numbers and then remove them. But Setting the interval to 1 can cause you trouble unless you put it back to auto at a later time.

This code does not solve the problem in my case as a result of having to change axis interval property. Please suggest if anyone has an alternative suggestion.

```
    private void Chart_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CustomLabel> list = new List<CustomLabel>();
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\\d+$");

        foreach (CustomLabel l in chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels)
        {
            if(!r.IsMatch(l.Text))
            {
                list.Add(l);
            } 
        }

        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CustomLabel l in list)
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Remove(l);
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;

        }
    }
```